# Minitest Rails: RuntimeError: not a redirect! 200 OK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

I wrote a small integration test, to test my login for an application. I think my code is fine but I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: not a redirect! 200 OK
```

I understand that it means that it is not redirecting. But when I do this in my application everything works fine, also the redirect. I can login and get redirected to the specified url. So I have no clue what I could change to make the test pass.

This is my code:

```
require 'test_helper'
class AuthFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "AuthFlowsTest" do 
    get "/agents/sign_in"
    assert_equal 200, status  
    post "/agents/sign_in", params: { email: agents(:one).email,
      password: agents(:one).password }

    assert_response :redirect
    follow_redirect!
    assert_equal 200, status
    assert_equal "/organizations", path
  end 
end
```

And this is my fixtures file:

```
one: 
  email: test@test.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(Agent, '123456') %>
```

Maybe a problem with Devise? I'm clueless.... Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is your sign_in action redirecting after you sign in?

Comment: yes it is redirecting. thats why Im confused....

Comment: fixed by: post "/agents/sign_in", params: { agent: { email: 
  agents(:one).email, password: "123456789" } }